# Convert JSON String to JSON

Tags: json, gson, spring-data-jpa

I am querying Postgres DB for retrieving JSONB format data using spring data JPA, which is stored like this in DB :

```
"{
"name":"abc",
"place"="xyz"
}"
```

but I am getting the response back with out double quotes, is there a way that I get the double quotes using spring data JPA or convert back to JSON with double quotes?

I tried new GSON().tJson() and ObjectMapper but no luck any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you give your sample model/bean class for that type

Comment: Just for your information, a JSON **is** a string (JavaScript Object Notation), you want to convert a JSON to an object (an actual JavaScript Object) . And as already given in an answer, `JSON.parse(yourString)` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your *JSON* object format is quite good and you should have no issue **deserializing** it back to a *POJO*.

Assuming your *POJO* class is named `Template`, here down a sample de-serialization implementation:

```java
public class SerializationTest {

    private static final String OBJECT = "{\n"
          + "\"name\":\"abc\",\n"+
          "\"place\"=\"xyz\"\n"+
          "}";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Serialized object:\n" + OBJECT);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Template template = gson.fromJson(OBJECT, Template.class);

        System.out.println(template);
    }

    private static class Template {

        private String name;

        private String place;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getPlace() {
            return place;
        }

        public void setPlace(String place) {
            this.place = place;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Template{" +
                  "name='" + name + '\'' +
                  ", place='" + place + '\'' +
                  '}';
        }
    }
}
```